# Question Magento htaccess - FTP subfolder are reachable for everyone

Tags: security, server-setup, htaccess, ftp

I clean installed a new Magento shop and everything works fine. I only have a problem with the protection of the subfolders.

For example i can type in the URL

www.exampleshop.com/vendor

this url is reachable and i dont know how i can protect it.

Answer (score 2):

The best would be to move your /vendor folder one level up which means it's outside the DocumentRoot.

Otherwise:
Given that you use Apache, create an new file `.htaccess` in your vendor folder:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

You should also do the same for your .modman folder if this one is within the document root.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Did you mean i should create a new htaccess in the DocumentRoot or in the vendor folder?

Comment: Yep, you're right. That .htaccess needs to go to the vendor folder. Updated my answer. Sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: And another question. when i move the vendor folder one level up could it be that my shop is broken because of the links? and its not only my vendor folder. should i place a htaccess like this in every folder who is reachable?

Comment: Yes, that could possibly break your setup. Actually it depends on your deployment strategy. It makes sense to deploy only what is really needed to the live-system and lock all folders that don't need to be accessed by the browser (.git folder, .modman, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got another problem. My "JS" and my "media" folder are reachable and i put a htaccess in with your code. When i do that my shop design get broken. I think because of the shop cant get the images and javascripts. But i will protect that folders.. is there any option?

Comment: Those folders should not be reachable by default. Are you sure you copied those folders correctly?

Comment: I downloaded magento and i extracted it and then i uploaded the folders to my ftp server. Have you any idea what i can do?